# Why does Ubuntu menu behave like OSX?

Tags: window

One of the annoyances of OSX was that the menu bar is locates in the top task bar and not on the window of the application you are running.

Its like playing ping pong having to move your cursor to the top of the screen instead of the window you are using.

Is there a way to make the menu return to the Application where it is supposed to be instead of the top where the task bar is?